# I want make a list with numbers

Tags: laravel, laravel-pagination

I want to make a list with numbers for example ( 1. lorem 2. ipsum 3 ...) I have pagination in the list.
I'm trying to get an index from an array

```
    @foreach ($items as $index => $item)
       <li>$index + 1</li>
    @endforeach
```

This works, but when I use pagination, all pages start at 1
When using pagination, how can the numbering continue on the second page and not start over?

Comment: How many items are there per page? Or is that a variable? You need that information to be able to calculate the number. Also is it an ordered list `<ol>` or unordered list `<ul>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@foreach ($items as $index => $item)
   <li>{{ ($items->currentPage() - 1) * $items->perPage() + $index + 1}} </li>
@endforeach
```

or you can it like this

```
@php
    $start = ($items->currentPage() - 1) * $items->perPage();
@endphp

@foreach ($items as $index => $item)
   <li>{{ $start + $index + 1}} </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Or `<li>{{ $items->firstItem() + $index }} </li>` could work as well